# Alternating Row colors for an HTML Fieldset

Tags: html, css

How can the browser display alternating colors for an HTML fieldset?  I have form elements that are members of a fieldset, and each row must be an alternating color.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Please post your markup/css and preferably an example (http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: What do you mean alternate colors in a fieldset? The background color of the fieldset?

Comment: I think he wants each `input` elements to have their own background color...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358350/alternate-background-colors-for-list-items

Comment: I don't have any markup right now, I just have a fieldset with form elements inside.  My PM just told me(days before this is due) that each form element should be linked with its name by having alternating colors... similar to having alternating rows in a table colored.

Comment: *I don't have any markup right now, I just have a fieldset with form elements inside.* This is nonsensical; the second part of the sentence appears to directly contradict the first. This question is going in the "not a real question" direction.

Comment: what language are you writing in? I assume you have access to jquery?

Comment: As best as I can tell, this is what you're describing: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ZLA7Z/

Comment: @Jared Farrish.  I don't have the current markup, but I do have the old markup that I have to change... Cheese and Rice, do I have to spell it out?  (Why yes I do, I am writing this :-) ).  But the cynicism is appreciated.  Thatnks for the jsfiddle btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<style>
label:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #ddd;
   display:block;
}  
<style>

<fieldset>
   <label> Input <input type="text"></label>
   <label> Input <input type="text"></label>
   <label> Input <input type="text"></label>
   <label> Input <input type="text"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Actually that is no good.  It doesn't work in IE 8 (peace of #$%%^)...  It took me a couple of days to figure out what on earth I was doing wrong, but I finally did it. :(

Comment: Well, IE8 compliance was never part of the requirements, was it? ;) If it's dynamically created you can give every 2nd label it's own class and then style that.

Comment: shouldn't you be able to add a class to each label via jquery using the same methodology as label:nth-child(odd)?  That is what I attempted to do, but with no luck.  It adds a class to each label thus giving me one big ugly mess.

Comment: You can use the same selector for the query so it'll select every 2nd label, and then you add a class to all of those.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it...

I have a jquery function...

$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#e8eef4");

That takes every odd row (I broke down and got table rows :-(... Unfortunately, the suedo-class for tr (tr:nth-child(odd)) doesn't work in IE 8 either... nested parenths ftw btw).

And that my friends is that.

Comment: Try this: `$("tr:odd").addClass("oddrow");` and `.oddrow { background-color:#e8eef4; }`