# Adding <li> and </li> to <ul> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

In my Wordpress page I have many posts featuring song lyrics. I wish to style alternate lines of lyrics differently. I so far have the basics sorted, but I need helping using jQuery to prefix and suffix each line of lyrics with `<li>` and `<ul>` in order to use CSS styles to apply styles to odd and even lines as I saw in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358350/alternate-background-colors-for-list-items).
My HTML currently looks like the following:

```
<div id="lyricstext" style="overflow: auto; height: 340px; width: 640px;">
<ul>
Leave me alone
Leave me alone
Leave me alone
So just leave me alone
I said leave me alone
Leave me alone
Leave me alone
I’m not in the mood!
Piss off!
So when I say leave me alone
Nah T don’t play
I’m like Michael Jackson in a non-paedo way
The thought of mad partyin’, debauchery tortures me
My T-shirt reads “Fuck off and don’t talk to me”
Approaching every situation awkwardly
Like I’m mesmerized under some sort of sorcery
Who’s calling me? Don’t know – I’ll ignore it G
If I don’t share my time then is there more for me?
</ul>
</div>
```

So, I'm left wondering what JS to apply to the page to insert those `<li>`and `</li>`tags for me, in order to be able to style each alternate line differently. Thanks

Comment: An `<ul>` may not contain text nodes.

Comment: @pimvdb That's what OP wants to make it into `<li>` blocks. Can't you see the question?

Comment: @vasanth kumar: What I mean is that the original HTML is invalid. Your answer relies on this invalid HTML to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

```
$('#lyricstext ul').html($('#lyricstext ul').html().split('\n').map(function(v){
    return '<li>'+v+'</li>';
}));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/wZQQB/)

If you have more than one ul you'd need something like

```
$('#lyricstext ul').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split('\n').map(function(v){
       return '<li>'+v+'</li>';
    }));
});
```

And of course, like almost every code applied on the DOM, it must be called after the DOM is ready. So you have to wrap your code in a ready callback ;

```
$(function(){
    $('#lyricstext ul').html($('#lyricstext ul').html().split('\n').map(function(v){
        return '<li>'+v+'</li>';
    }));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
});
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Your example works wonders in jsFiddle, but I can't get it working on my site. I'm using Wordpress so I'm assuming I've called the script in wrong somehow. I'll keep working. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Do you have more than one ul ? If so you'd need each. I edited with how it can be done.

Comment: No I don't. Per post only one `<ul>` in play. Like my original example, but the text is a bit longer. There are a couple of other html tags in the middle, but limited to the odd `<em>` or `<strong>`. I put the script in my single.php and I know it's loaded from looking at the Page Source, but it has no effect on the text in my post.

Comment: Is the script executed after the post is loaded ? You might want to check by doing `console.log($('#lyricstext ul'))` and looking at [the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview#access).

Comment: I get two related errors. 1) SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (little green arrow points at the hashtag) and the second ReferenceError: $ is not defined. Thanks again. Any light you can shed?

Comment: It looks like jQuery isn't imported. You should have a <script> element in your header importing it.

Comment: http://www.beta.hiphopinenglish.com/phi-life-cypher-drop-bombs/ - one of the pages in question. jQuery is called, but obviously not doing its job!

Comment: Some progress has been made! Now the text in the div is disappearing!

Comment: Can you try with `split('\r')` ?

Comment: That's returned the div text, but no luck applying the li's. For reference: Called jQuery and your script in header. Is it worth applying your snippet to footer instead?

Comment: You can't simply call my code in the header without waiting for the dom to be ready. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I'm a bit lost now. It won't work for me. I've added it to functions.php and still no joy. This is the code I used:
    
    function liscript() {
    if( wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('#lyricstext ul').html($('#lyricstext ul').html().split('\n').map(function(v){
        return '<li>'+v+'</li>';
    }));
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'liscript' );

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I'm missing it entirely. Thanks for your help if you can help again

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this:

```
var html = $('#lyricstext ul').html().split('\n').map(function(text){
    return '<li>'+text+'</li>';
});
$('#lyricstext ul').html(html);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, try this:

```
var $ul = $("#lyricstext ul");
var lines = $ul.text().split('\n');

$.each(lines, function() {
    $ul.append('<li>' + this + '</li>');
    $ul.find('li:odd').addClass('alternate');
});​
```