# How to make this JavaScript code more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently adding a class to every 4th div that has a certain class. However, is there a easy to count them and add it to every 4th div automatically? Because currently I am doing it like this:

```
$(".item:eq(0)").addClass('first');
$(".item:eq(4)").addClass('first');
$(".item:eq(8)").addClass('first');
$(".item:eq(12)").addClass('first');
$(".item:eq(16)").addClass('first');
```

Which means that if there are 100 of these divs, I would need to have so many of these lines. Thanks.

Comment: Store the result of `$(".item")` in a variable first, then use jQuery's `.eq()` method to get the specific ones

Comment: Similar questions answered already: Please see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358350/alternate-background-colors-for-list-items

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS has a [selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) for exactly this scenario:

```
$(".item:nth-child(4n+1)").addClass('first');
```

If they are all siblings, but have other elements interspersed, you can use [`:nth-of-type`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) instead.

If they are not siblings, no selector will help you.

Comment: This will only work, though, if the `.item` elements are the only children of a common parent...

Comment: Great! But why is it 4n+1?

Comment: @LightStyle: Because CSS, unlike jQuery, is 1-based.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I didn't know it!

Comment: `If they are not siblings, no selector will help you.` - why does the solution require **one** selector and that's it? You can easily filter, or at least "cache" the `.item` elements first, making it more efficient than the OP

Comment: @Ian: So? The selector still won't help.

Comment: @SLaks I'm just confused why you think a selector is required to do all the work. Surely, `var items = $(".item");` and working with `items` (like with `.filter()` or simply using `.eq()` several times) is faster than querying 5 times. Anyways, `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()` are nowhere near equivalent to `:eq()`. The OP is using `:eq()` for a reason - they are just trying to get specific indexes from the whole collection found, nothing to do with siblings

Comment: FYI `:nth-child(4n+1)` will do the same in **jQ** and **CSS**, `+1` indicates that the count should start/include the *first* element. (So no `0`/`1` trickeries in here) `°L°`

Comment: @Ian: I'm aware of that, but the selector isn't actually helping.  I would have mentioned that option, but lonesomeday beat me to it.

Answer (score 4):

If the elements all have one parent, and the parent has no other children, you can use `nth-child`. If that isn't the case, it will be a bit more complicated. Something like this may work:

```
$('.item').filter(function(idx) {
    return idx % 4 === 0;
}).addClass('first');
```

A slightly faster solution, though slightly less intuitive, uses `addClass` directly:

```
$('.item').addClass(function(idx) {
    return idx % 4 === 0 ? 'first' : '';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I like SLaks answer. However, you can also create a loop in JS:

```
var i = 0;
var itemArray = $('.item');
var lastNumber = itemArray.length;
while(i <= lastNumber) {
    itemArray[i].className += ' first';
    i += 4;
}
```

Comment: just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Was my answer really that horrible? It's probably faster than using jQuery functions to loop through.

Comment: @MarcMarta Try it. It will be far, far slower, because it has to create the jQuery object and do the selection `lastNumber/4` times. jQuery's loop is fairly efficient.

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't use a loop and agree very much with slaks answer. But its sometimes nice to know alternative approaches. 'More efficient' than author's own solution. Edit: I take back the unacceptable comment after the edit.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. Check the answer now. jQuery's loop will never be as efficient as if you write the code natively - it has to create a function and run it.

Comment: Yes, that's much better. Though it does need to be `$('.item')` or `document.getElementsByClassName('item')`...

Comment: Fixed again. Typo city today, sorry.

Comment: @MarcMarta even after your edit `lastNumber` is not defined `°L°`. Immagine one starting with code and looking at your demo would think that lastNumber is some kind of supernatural variable... `°?°`

Comment: @RokoCBuljan That is for the user to define themselves. I don't know what the extent of the last number is.

Comment: @MarcMarta you can easily get it using `.length` on `itemArray`

Comment: @RokoCBuljan True. I was thinking actually in terms of backwards loops when I started writing this for even faster looping. You are correct, I will modify.