# Changing the specific row's background

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently, I am working on a project which is Book Store Web Application. I want to change the background of the rows like one row is grey, the next row is white and goes on like this.Also my task is doing this using CSS.

[image]

You can see in picture. I want to change the "Novel" row grey, I want the next row which is "Horror" stay white and change "Adventure" row to grey and it goes on like this. The datas come from the database one by one and I cannot reach them one by one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternate background colors for list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358350/alternate-background-colors-for-list-items)

Comment: It is not the exact solution, because the datas come from the database one by one and I cannot reach all of them. I think i have to use @foreach kinda syntax but as I said I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: Yes, I tried the solution and It does not effect as i wanted but that is because of me. I used the wrong one. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using asp.net MVC I will assume you are using bootstrap.

All you need to do is add `.table-striped` on `<tbody></tbody>`

or follow this example:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  ...
</table>
```

**For a plain CSS solution try this:**

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Bootstrap 5 striped table docs: [Striped table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/content/tables/#striped-rows)

Comment: Bootstrap is okay too, but my task is do this using css. thanks anyway :)

Comment: I have updated the solution. Try it out

Comment: thank you so much. This is the answer i want :)

Comment: Glad that I could help (: